# Qt c++ Read access violation when I try to read Empty data of other dialog.ui

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem of read access violation.

What I want to do is the following:

I have two forms : mainwindow.ui and dialog.ui

In **dialog.h** I code this

```
public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

    double getValue();

    QString getName();
```

In **dialog.cpp** this

```
double Dialog::getValue()
{
    double result = 0.0;
    if(this->ui->lE_value->text().isEmpty())
    {
        result = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        QString set_value    = this->ui->lE_value->text();
        result = set_value.toDouble();
    }

    return result;
}

QString Dialog::getName()
{
    QString def_name = "def_name";
    if(this->ui->lE_name->text().isEmpty())
    {
        def_name = "def_name";
    }
    else
    {
        QString set_name    = this->ui->lE_name->text();
        def_name = set_name;
    }

    return def_name;
}
```

On the other hand in **mainwindow.h**

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    Dialog* form_dialog;
```

And in **mainwindow.cpp** I try

```
if(form_dialog->getValue() > 0)
{
    double value = form_dialog->getValue();
}
```

I expect the following

I need to follow with execution of code but if I don't open this dialog and set any values i get this error.

Exception read access violation

Comment: you need to first check if the dialog is instantiated. you cannot use it if there is no memory allocated to it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: Did you write `form_dialog = new Dialog()` somewhere before you use it?

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent your code from crashing but the you have to find out why form_dialog is NULL.

```
if (form_dialog != NULL) {
    if(form_dialog->getValue() > 0)
    {
        double value = form_dialog->getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may first initialize the pointer form_dialog to NULL in the MainWindow ctor and then try to allocate memory before testing its NULL value. Also you should reset the pointer to NULL if the allocated memory has been freed so that the test still makes sense.